# can we build automation bot with Azure bot framework?

Tags: automation, artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service

I want to achieve system automation task with the help of azure bot framework, currently we have step data in normal sentences Like:

```
   1) xyz.txt move to temp dir 
   2) read the file xyz.txt 
   3) delete the file xyz.txt
```

This is the one example there are random scenario for multiple tasks can we achieve this process with the help of azure bot and LUIS

Answer (score 0):

We can actually add natural language to the bot:

I have not tested in my lab, but below are few steps to acheive the same.

1. Create a LUIS app in the LUIS portal
2. Obtain values to connect to your LUIS app
3. Retrieve application information from the LUIS.ai portal
4. Update the settings file
5. Configure your bot to use your LUIS app
6. Test the bot

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp